# Release/Deployment/Packaging tools for multi-application systems

Tags: deployment, packaging, release-management

In our company we have the following situation: We have several (hardware) systems, each with several software applications. However, since the hardware is different, the software is also different in some cases. Furthermore, out in the field there are lots of different version combinations of the software.

For example, consider the following (simplified) situation:

**Systems:** `Sys1, Sys2, Sys3`
**Applications:** `App1, App2, App3, App4`, each with different versions

`Sys1` uses `App1 v1`, no `App2`, `App3 v3`, and `App4 v2`, while
`Sys2` uses `App1 v1`, `App2 v2`, `App3 v2`, and no `App4`, and
`Sys3` uses no `App1`, `App2 v3`, no `App3`, and `App4 v3`.

That is, every system uses a different set of applications, and also different versions of each application. Sometimes even different combination of versions, e.g. `App1 v1` is used with `App3 v2` and `App3 v3`.

Currently, we manage the set of valid software sets by manually copying the respective releases to the "internally public" folder which is accessed by the field service and production department. However, most of the time we only have the latest versions available, and it is hard for them to get any of the older version sets for a system.

**We would like to change this process to some sort of automated system. Are there software tools out there which can help with this process?** I was thinking of a software where you can set up different systems and different software components, create different versions of each, and then assign specific software versions to specific system versions.

Does anyone know a software which does just that? Or should we consider to completely change our packaging/deployment management? BTW: How is this process called "officially"?

To clarify things: We already use source control, build server, and the like. So this is not the point, but the missing step is the combination of several software components to a complete package which can be used by service and production. Since we do not use the build server for all software components (yet), I think it might be hard to let the build server take on this job, but I am open for suggestions.

**EDIT:**
Operating system is always Windows (2000, XP, Vista, 7, and 7 Embedded).
The applications are written in different languages, mainly C++ and C#, but our solution should be independent of the language, if possible.

Comment: What operating system(s) are you using, and what language(s) are you using for the applications ?

Comment: We use Windows (2000, XP, Vista, 7, and 7 Embedded). The applications are written in different languages, mainly C++ and C#, but our solution should be independent of the language, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I work in a very large company (thousands employees) and we have the same version for everybody, with a lot of applications. We have a pre-production environment, a developement environment, and the final releases. Of course, we work with java and all of our applications are webapps, so we don't have problems with our hardware.

I think this is the best environment. Everybody the same release.

Comment: This would be nice, but our systems use different hardware and therefore cannot use the same software most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

We make a free (really) tool that's pretty good at doing exactly this. It currently supports Solaris (Intel & Sparc), Linux, Mac OS and Windows target servers. You can get a pretty good idea at what it does with the [video tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_query=kwateesdcm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We will investigate this software.